# Page scroll issue when using dropdown menu

Tags: views, javascript

I am using a view in this page, and using [sexy exposed](https://www.drupal.org/project/sexy_exposed) module for filter criteria.
The page shows the horizontal scrollbar. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide it with CSS using `body { overflow-x: hidden; }`.

It would be better to figure out why the scroll is happening, but it's hard to troubleshoot that without having access to your site.